# Ubuntu message on boot up: problems found in /

Tags: 14.04, boot, grubrescue

Ubuntu keeps incessantly giving me the grub rescue problem. Everytime it happens, I do what this thread says:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash

It works, but it's ad hoc, as this keeps on happening almost everytime I reboot/boot my laptop.

I don't really care about typing it everytime, but i'm highly ignorant on what is happening, and would like to know if it could present (or be consequence of) some security problem (e.g. malware or viruses).

This time, it also said there were errors found in / and game me some options, like fix errors, skip or manually recover.

What possible causes can be making this happen? Could it present some security issue?